# Proving the general formula for conditional expectation of a Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, proof-writing, poisson-distribution

I am studying a course on Stochastic Processes and encountered the following proof exercise on Poisson Processes:

> If $N$ is a Poisson Process with intensity $\lambda$, then for $0<s<t$ where $k \leq n$ are non-negative integers, then prove the following:
> $$ P(N(s) = k | N(t) = n) = \binom{n}{k} \Big{(} \frac{s}k \Big{)}^k \Big{(} 1 - \frac{s}t \Big{)}^{n-k}$$

I know that $N(t)$ (and analogously, $N(s)$) will follow the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t $. This allows me to use Bayes’ Formula for the conditional expectation to see that:

$$ P(N(s) = k | N(t) = n) = \frac{P(N(s) = k \text{ and } N(t) = n)}{ P(N(t) = n)}$$
$$  = \frac{n!}{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n} P(N(s) = k \space \text{and} \space N(t) = n) $$
$$ =  \frac{n!}{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n} \Big{(}P(N(t) = n | N(s) = k)\frac{e^{-\lambda s}(\lambda s)^k}{k!} \Big{)}$$

Then simplifying the above expression yields the following:

$$ = \frac{n! \space e^{-\lambda (s - t)}s^k}{k! \lambda ^{n-k}t^n} P(N(t) = n | N(s) = k)$$

Assuming this is right, this doesn't seem to be particularly close to the desired form. Is there another approach or perhaps a way to complete my attempt so far that I am not seeing? One thing worth noting is that I haven't really used any of the properties of a Poisson Process yet, really I've just treated $N(s)$ and $N(t)$ as two Poisson distributions - which may be my mistake.

I would be grateful for any assistance with this exercise.

Comment: You are almost there. Did you try substituting the value of $\Pr(N(t) = n| N(s) = k)$?

Comment: What would I substitute for this? @sudeep5221

Comment: $\Pr(N(t) = n| N(s) = k) = \Pr(N(t-s) = n-k)$ using the independence properties of the Poisson process.

Comment: Does that follow from the fact that $N_t - N_s$ are independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$? @sudeep5221

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note that $N_t - N_s$ has the same distribution as $N_{t-s}$ because it is a Poisson process (this fact is important here). This follows using the memoryless property of exponential random variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is that independence implication straightforward to see or will it require me to read through a proof to appreciate? @sudeep5221

Comment: Intuitively it should be straightforward, but if you are new to Poisson process, I would suggest you read the proofs once so that you get a better feel for the topic.

Comment: Thanks again for the hint. I've written up the remainder of the proof as an answer now @sudeep5221

Comment: No worries! The answer looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing where I left off, using the hint given in the comments, I left off at the following point:

> $$ P(N(s)=k|N(t)=n) = \frac{(n!) \space e^{-\lambda (s - t)}s^k}{k! \lambda ^{n-k}t^n} P(N(t) = n | N(s) = k)$$

Note that the following result holds: $$P(N(t)=n|N(s)=k)=P(N(t−s)=n−k)$$ due to the fact that Poisson Processes satisfy the independence property that $N_t - N_s$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_s$ for any $0<s<t< \infty$.

Therefore the above simplifies as follows:

$$P(N(s)=k|N(t)=n) = \frac{n! \space e^{-\lambda (s - t)}s^k}{k! \lambda ^{n-k}t^n}P(N(t−s)=n−k)$$
$$ = \frac{n! \space e^{-\lambda (s - t)}s^k}{k! \lambda ^{n-k}t^n} \times \frac{e^{- \lambda (t-s)}(\lambda (t-s))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$$
$$ = \frac{n! }{k!(n-k)! } \times \frac{s^k((t-s))^{n-k}}{t^n}$$
$$ = \frac{n! }{k!(n-k)! } \times \Big{(}\frac{s}{t}\Big{)}^k \times \Big{(} \frac{t-s}{t}\Big{)}^{n-k}$$
$$ = \binom{n}{k} \times \Big{(}\frac{s}{t}\Big{)}^k \times \Big{(} 1 - \frac{s}{t}\Big{)}^{n-k} \quad \quad \square$$